# Converting feet and inches to inches (multiple inputs into one input)

Tags: java, bluej

This program has me stumped. I'm trying to figure out a way to convert input from this:

```
    System.out.print("Enter your height in inches (e.g. 57): ");
    String height = in.nextLine();
    height += in.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
```

and turn it into just inches. How do I separate the feet from the inches, change said feet to inches and combine them into a sum of inches once again?

Comment: Can you clarify the steps that the program is supposed to execute again? They aren't quite clear to me. I thought I knew what you meant but after answering I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("Enter your height in inches (e.g. 57): ");
int heightInInches = in.nextInt();
int heightInFeet = heightInInches / 12;
int heightInchesRemaining = heightInInches % 12;
System.out.println(heightInFeet + "\' " + heightInchesRemaining + "\"");
```

You can convert into ft. and in. format by doing that. Then do whatever you need to with the rest of the operations that you described.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your question and sample code is confusing so I will base my answer on your last statement. From my understanding, you ask the user to input his height in feet first then the remaining inches and convert this info to inches only (e.g 5'7 to 67 inches)

```
System.out.print("Enter your height in feet. (e.g, 5 if your height is 5'7) : ");
int height = in.nextInt() * 12;
System.out.print("Enter your height in inches (e.g, 7 if your height is 5'7) : ");
height += in.nextInt();
System.out.println(height);
```